# Grid Vertical Positioning with Row

Tags: css, html

I have view like this:
[image]

And my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 700px">
    <eds-tile-title>User on Shift</eds-tile-title>
    <!-- <eds-gauge [settings]="gaugeScore"></eds-gauge> -->
  </div>
  <div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 200px">
    <eds-tile-title>Count of Ticket Closed</eds-tile-title>
  </div>
  <div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 200px">
    <eds-tile-title>Total Ticket</eds-tile-title>
  </div>
  <div eds-tile class="xl-8" style="height: 400px">
    <eds-tile-title>User on Shift Indicator</eds-tile-title>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should i do if i want to move the User on Shift Indicator box under Count of Ticket Closed box and Total Ticket box ?

Help me guys, Thanks...

Comment: please add css as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest one layout into another, two columns as 4/8, and then in the 8 column you can make a row full and the other half/half.

Maybe its simpler with the code

```
<div class="row">
    <div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 700px">
        <eds-tile-title>User on Shift</eds-tile-title>
        <!-- <eds-gauge [settings]="gaugeScore"></eds-gauge> -->
    </div>
    <div class="xl-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div eds-tile class="xl-6" style="height: 200px">
                <eds-tile-title>Count of Ticket Closed</eds-tile-title>
            </div>
            <div eds-tile class="xl-6" style="height: 200px">
                <eds-tile-title>Total Ticket</eds-tile-title>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div eds-tile class="xl-12" style="height: 400px">
                <eds-tile-title>User on Shift Indicator</eds-tile-title>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using class **xl-12** for "User on Shif" div and move it below - "Count of Ticket Closed" and "Total Ticket"

```html
<div class="row">
  <div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 200px">
    <eds-tile-title>Count of Ticket Closed</eds-tile-title>
  </div>
  <div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 200px">
    <eds-tile-title>Total Ticket</eds-tile-title>
  </div>
  <div eds-tile class="xl-12" style="height: 700px">
    <eds-tile-title>User on Shift</eds-tile-title>
    <!-- <eds-gauge [settings]="gaugeScore"></eds-gauge> -->
  </div>
  <div eds-tile class="xl-8" style="height: 400px">
    <eds-tile-title>User on Shift Indicator</eds-tile-title>
  </div>
</div>
```